# onbeforeunload load in javascript help

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in javascript below:

```
function ExitPage(){return 'Wait!';}


<body onbeforeunload="return ExitPage();">
```

I would like to run some codes when the user clicks on the "cancel" button. How will I accomplish this?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I see no buttons. belly or otherwise

Comment: Do you want to have an alert pop up that says 'Wait!'?

Comment: When the page is closed, there will be a confirm box that will appear having an OK and Cancel button. When the user clicks on the OK button, it will continue to close the page. But when the user clicks on the Cancel button, I would like to run some codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. At least not in a safe way - the only think you could do is starting a timer in the `onbeforeunload` handler that runs for e.g. 10 seconds. If the page is still open after this time this timer then runs your code.